# Retrieve a deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Is there a way to retrieve a deleted question I have asked?

I deleted it because I had a duplicate, but after further reading I understood that's it's not really the same question, and I want mine back.

Comment: Post the question link.

Comment: I don't have it.

Comment: Nevermind - found it in the inbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find your questions (even the deleted ones) [through your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/622/adam-matan?tab=questions). Deleted questions show up with a slightly red background.

If you have many, there's a "[recently deleted](https://askubuntu.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/622)" link at the bottom of that list.

Answer (score 4):

This was changed relatively recently (in 2022). You can now find all your deleted questions/deleted answers. (See also the entries about January 2021 here: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445#375078).)

If you go to your profile and to the [question tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=questions), simply scroll to the bottom and click on *deleted questions*. You can get to the list of deleted answers in the same way.

Here is a direct link that should get you to the list of your deleted questions: https://askubuntu.com/users/deleted-questions/current